# Questions vs. discussion openers

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

If I correctly understand the pretty graph in the [about](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/about) section, this site is also supposed to serve as a forum, yet I am getting the impression that discussions are discouraged and the simple question-answer model preferred. So I want to ask you if you think it's OK to post a question which clearly is not a case of someone wanting to learn something they don't know, but rather which aims to open a discussion so as to learn about the different points of view, or simply get a little more social.

From what I see in the stats, the site does not fare terribly well. Perhaps an attempt at giving it a slightly more casual character can help improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StackExchange sites are Q&A sites, i.e. Question & Answer sites. Check this MSO question about this topic: "[Is StackOverflow a forum?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/176533)". It's about SO but still related, I think. :)

Someone asks questions and the community answers. There is no discussion, except for this meta site, where we treat about the site and not about the site's topic.

There even exists a close-reason against questions inviting for discussion:

[image]

Not only that, even questions can't be too scope-wide, as you must ask for something specific. Not necessarily something too specific, i.e. a particular example, but a specific topic/question.

Comment: Well, oh well. What about questions to which a single, widely accepted answer does not exist? Say I asked "Is phoneme a psychological reality?" -- that's something that can be discussed, there are arguments on both sides and nobody knows what the truth really is. Is this type of questions out, too?

Comment: @KamilS. Yes and no. You can ask questions that you don't know the answer to, and if an answer doesn't exist, you'll get answers like "There isn't an answer yet"; But you must preferably ask questions about problems and situations you face. You can ask theoretical questions but they must be reasonably scoped and specific.